# Access object references if one cannot transfer it a parameter / return list

Tags: java, object, reference

Let us assume, we have a nice little Java Project using the classes `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`.
To access an object, its methods or attributes, one needs a link to it: the instance ID or reference. It is easy if I just created an instance of the class in vm current class:

In class `A`:

```
B bi = new B();
```

Using `bi`, I can access all properties and methods provided by class `B` in class `A`.

But, when I'm in class `B` now:

```
C ci =  new C();
```

Of course, in class `B` I  can access all provided by `C` / `ci`. But how to take advantage of `C` / `ci` in `A`? There is no object reference available. 
Just creating a new one is of no help: an additional instance of `C`, different working set of data.

I have found two ways.

1. All required from `C` by `A` must get encapsulated in `B` and gets called mediated via `B` / `bi` . The disadvantages are obvious.
2. I went back to my early `FORTRAN` experience and created a `Common` area. A purely static class. If `B` creates `ci`, it copies it refence into the area like:

   C ci = new C();
   Common.ci = ci;

Now it's easy to `A` to use  `C` / `ci`:

In class `A`:

```
Common.ci.setValue("Value");
```

A problem very alike arose to me in the famous paint method:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
```

All examples I have found so far carefully creates the data in the paint method itself. But how to handle, if the data to paint comes from outside? There is no parameter to provide an array to the paint method. I decided for a static reference like my solution `2`

None of these two potential solutions looks inspired or Java-style to me.
What is the solution of an experienced Java person to solve the issue?

Comment: You can provide a getter in B class for class C. So, in Class A you can say bi.getC().someMethod().

Comment: What's there in class C, some common functionality?

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. It makes sense. In my particular case, I have a central swing JFrame and some child windows, made of different classes, of course. The central and initial frame has to have the control over children and grandchilds.

Comment: Any idea, how to feed (In addition to some static class tricks)  that methods we have to override in order to use it and that do not accept additional project-specific parameters (like paintComponent)?